# How to change default settings in Digikam's Batch Queue Manager?

Tags: digikam

Digikam's Batch Queue Manager is very useful for batch renaming or editing metadata of files. However, every time I launch it I have to manually change some of the default settings - notably, the overwriting of files. This is tedious and often troublesome when I forget a setting.

[image]

How can I save my desired settings as default for the Batch Queue Manager?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of any way to change the default, but for all practical purposes the "Save Workflow" item under "Queues" (top left) should get you within a tab select and double click of where it sounds like you want to be.

"Save workflow" creates an entry on the "Workflow" tab (bottom right) which stores the tools and settings from the current queue. Double click on the name of the workflow to load.

Here's some I've just done (thanks for the question, by the way - you've saved me a bit of time in future) :

[image]

More information in [the digiKam manual](https://docs.digikam.org/en/batch_queue/bqm_workflow.html).